# Menus not aligning in Center and aside overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have created a pen Here → https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/NpKZpN but I am facing 2 challenges →

1 → You can see that the content in the right hand side aside is overlapping the footer. I tried to set height:auto to many elements but still that could not fix the issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZXkY.png)

2 → I want that my menu items should be exactly in the middle of that top row.
[image: Centred Menu Items]

Code Here →

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- <meta charset="utf-8"> -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Responsive Two Column Layout (Left Column Fluid)</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="max-width">

            <header>
               <div class="logo floating-inline">
                   <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/projectsts/generic/logo2.png" alt="">
               </div><!-- logo -->

               <nav class="floating-inline">
                  <ul class="nav inline-items">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </nav>
            </header>

            <div class="post-title">
                <h1>Responsive Two Column Layout Left Column → Fluid, Right Column → Adaptive.</h1>
            </div> <!-- post-title -->
            <div class="site-container">
                <main class="left-column">
                    <h2>Left Column (fluid)</h2>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </main>

                <aside class="right-column">
                    <h2>Right Column</h2>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </aside>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <p><a href="#">Contact Us</a> | <a href="#">FAQ</a> | <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></p>
                <p>&copy;2017 Copyright Text Here</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Here →

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { margin: 0; }
.max-width {max-width: 1400px; margin: 0 auto;}
.site-container, .post-title, footer, header { position: relative; margin: .5em; }
.left-column, .right-column,.post-title, footer, header {  border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 1.25em; }
.left-column { margin-bottom: .5em; }
.floating-inline{display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav > li,
.nav > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.inline-items {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.inline-items li {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.inline-items li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.inline-items li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em ) {
  .left-column { margin-right: 19.5em; }

    .right-column { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 18.75em; }
}
```

Please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: consider changing the tittle to something that actually asks for what you need.

Comment: Can you explain Issue 1 a bit more, possibly with screenshot/image

Comment: Done Sir. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**solution to first problem**

https://codepen.io/obedparla/pen/xqxBXW

Basically the issue is the way you're making the divs "float" next to each other. You are *forcing* them to stay in place by using absolute positioning. Absoulute positioned elements don't respect the boxes or spaces of other elements, they're on top of all of them.

```
.clear{
  clear: both;
}
.left-column{
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.right-column{
  width: 28%;
  float: right;
}
```

I've added the following to your css, at the end, to override your current css. It sets the elements to float, and the corrects widths, giving the same effect but without your issue. This is the correct way of doing it. You can also check flex-box.

You'll also need to

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

between the floating elements and the footer, to clean the floats (otherwise they'll overlap on the footer).

**solution to second problem**

Since you're using inline-blocks to align the logo and the text, you'd need to set the width of each of the elements.

The working pen is here: https://codepen.io/obedparla/pen/xqxBXW

The only thing I added was:

```
nav.floating-inline{
 width: 70%;
}

ul.nav.inline-items{
  text-align: center;
}
```

By giving a width to the floating inline elements (the nav) you can then use text-align center and they'll be centered in between those 70% width.

You can play around with this to achieve the exact result you want. Giving the logo a bigger width and such.

For the first issue, the content is not overlaping the footer your codepen. Could you submit a screenshot if that's still the case?

Comment: If you remove 1 <p> element from the left side container, then you will see the issue

Comment: aha. Interesting. Will check

Comment: I have uploaded the overlapping image. I need something like this → Logo - Menu Text(Centered) - Social Media Icons(Right of that row)

Comment: Check my answer again, both questions answered @WordpressNovice hopefully that's what you needed.

Comment: If ultimately I have to use the float then what's the advantage in using this  → display: inline-block; Isn't it a better practice to use this instead of float? Pardon me If I am talking something non-sense as I am a beginner.

Comment: no worries! we all had to learn this stuff. There is no strict "best practice" when it comes to these type of layouts, it really depends on what you need to create. However, for a simple side-by-side layout as yours, floating elements are the way to go. If you don't have to support old browsers or IE, check flex-box, flex is the future, but for now, float is good.

Comment: @WordpressNovice keep in mind that the semanthics of inline-block are that elements will be next to each other, each of their boxes follow one another. You can get the effect you want with it too, but usually floats can be easier to handle, however, you were using absolute position, which is kind of forcing the elements to be where you want them to be instead.

Comment: Sir Positions are the most difficult thing for me. Any reference that can clear the concept?

Comment: Yeah don't worry, I think they're not really intuitive. I'd recommend css-tricks.com. Check this one https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: Basically Fixed is: it ALWAYS stays where you put it. Relative, relative to itself, absolute, relative to its parent.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZXkY.png   https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/NpKZpN Please check them for the overlapping issue.

Comment: and if you found my answer useful, could you please accept it as the correct answer by clicking the check icon? Thanks :)!

Comment: you still have the position: absolutely. Check my codepen to see the example using floats. https://codepen.io/obedparla/pen/xqxBXW

Comment: Can you Put lot of content in aside in your pen please?

Comment: @WordpressNovice you can modify it from your side too, they're open pens. It will still fit fine. https://codepen.io/obedparla/pen/xqxBXW

Comment: Thanks sir. Can you please tell me what exactly did you change so that your text is not overlapping. I means exactly what CSS did you changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="floating-inline" style="width: 80%;text-align: center;">
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
header{
    height:100px;
}
nav{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    margin:20px auto;
}
.logo{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: If ultimately I have to use the float then what's the advantage in using this → display: inline-block; Isn't it a better practice to use this instead of float? Pardon me If I am talking something non-sense as I am a beginner.

Comment: @WordpressNovice ya ur correct either use float left or inline-block, i forgot to write to remove that property.